# Certain commands dont work . How do I fix it?

Tags: command-line, bash, macosx

I've successfully managed to install Ubuntu server 18.04. Most of my sudo commands work fine, however, I am having issues running the cd/cp commands. ie: whenever I type `cd/` I get:

```
-bash: cd/: No such file or directory.
```

The same thing happens when I type `cat auth.log` and when I use <kbd>q</kbd> to quit. The program suggested installing python, which I did; but still no results. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Most likely you are missing a space. Try `cd /`. Are you sure `auth.log` exists where you are expecting it?

Comment: 1. space is missing: `cd /` 2. `auth.log` obviously is not in your working directory (if it exists at all). 3. where are you using q on?

Comment: Check out the howto: https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0020.php

Answer (score 2):

Let's divide this to subquestions:

> whenever I type 'cd/' I get '-bash: cd/: No such file or directory'.

When we whats the usage of the command `cd` (`cd --help`) we will found as follows:

> cd: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
>
> ```
> Change the shell working directory.
> ```

What you are mistaking is that you are missing a space after using command `cd` and the system is recognizing this as command `cd/` not a command `cd /`. This will cause the error you are mentioning.

---

We can do the same for using `cat`, be first sure to use `cat --help` to find out how this commands has to be used, or google it.

Be sure you are using an existing file otherwise, the cat will output

> cat: auth.log: No such file or directory

Which you may misunderstand as `cat` is not existing.

`cd`, as well as `cat`, are default Ubuntu commands which are always present, until you uninstall them, which I am not sure if it's possible.

---

I believe the same applies for 'q' which is just closing output on the terminal if needed.

---

I would recommend looking at the basic Ubuntu usage docs they are providing [link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/command-line-for-beginners#1-overview) for the beginning!

Comment: Thank you as well, I got it to work :)